# Can a failed SSD have zero bad sectors?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, hard-drive-failure

Today, my Windows 7 pc decided it didn't want to boot out of the blue. After the bios screen, all I see is a black screen. No windows logo, no text, just black.

I've ran chkdsk off a boot CD and it found zero issues, no bad sectors. I can also freely explore the filesystem on my SSD where Windows 7 is installed.

I've made no changes to my bios, or really anything recently. Any ideas what's going on?

Update: I've also run sfc - no issues found.

Comment: Try running "bootrec /ScanOs" from your boot CD's command line to see if your OS is being detected.

Comment: Yep. It found it. "Total identified Windows installations: 1 E:\Windows"

Comment: You should be able to use the Windows 7 install disk to fix simple boot issues.  There are lots of sites that explain how to do this.  Then of course, run MalwareBytes to make sure you don't have some kind of malware that did this to you.

Comment: Also, SSDs will lie to you about bad sectors, since they have internal programming to automatically remap portions of the flash memory that has reached its 10,000 write lifetime.  Usually it will just remap things internally then report all is well.  Get a program that looks at SMART - Crystal(something - I forget the whole name) can tell you more about whatever is happening.